# Bind IP in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, remotewebdriver, webautomation

I have 4 devices connected to 4 different physical interfaces (192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.5) on the same PC. They all have the same IP address (lets say 192.168.1.1). I want to bind the local IP address to Selenium so that i know what device's webpage I am opening. I tried using RemoteWebDriver:

```
'DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();

 IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://192.168.1.2:4444"), dc);
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://192.168.1.1");'
```

But, I keep getting the following error:

Error 403 Forbidden for Proxy

if I add "/wd/hub" to the Uri, the driver will listen on 127.0.0.1 and I won't know which device webpage is open.

Is there any resolution to this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: are you getting the error from the **GoToUrl** call or from the driver initialization?

Comment: From the driver initialization. I have the selenium standalone server running on the same PC for the remotewebdriver. If I use port 192.168.1.2:9515, I am getting:

Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 192.168.1.2:9515
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)

Comment: well the problem is not with selenium.. I'm afraid you will have to place your selenium in each interface you have.. if you want to identify the machine - please use a log and write a different name for each interface seperatly

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by "place your selenium in each interface you have". I can run multiple instances of Selenium, but the Chromedriver will always listen on 127.0.0.1. And when I try to open "192.168.1.1", it will open any one of the 4 webpages.

Comment: please make a variable and set a different name for every instance of Selenium (hard-coded) - that way you will be able to identify each interface

Comment: Sorry, but I still didn't get how Selenium to relay the interface name to Chromedriver. My issue is that when I sent "driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://192.168.1.1");", driver will still listen on 127.0.0.1 and open a webpage from any one of those interfaces instead of opening it from a particular interface. Am I right? Can you give an example of how I can bind Selenium to an interface. i think my issue is more with Chromdriver than with Selenium.